# Magento category top navigation

Tags: magento, navigation, categories

I am having a priblem with magento displaying shared products in the top nav categories. Some of the products are members of more than one category but when I hover my navigation, they are displayed in only first category. Others remain empty.

Example

Category1: sub cat 1 -> sub cat 2 -> product 1, product 2, product 3

Category2: product 1

Category3: product 2

All Categories are in same root Category.

Is this even possible or will I have to modify the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following.

Reindex `Category Products` index and flush Magento cache.